# Editing a text file by prefixing a desired character to a particular type of string in the text file while retaining the rest of the strings

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a text file that contains both pure alphabetical and numerical strings.
My aim is to prefix each of the numerical strings with 0 if and only if they begin with 9 and retain rest of the strings in the original file to create a modified file. Foreg:

```
original file           modified file
  1 watsongone        4   watsongone
  2**978654321**      5  **0978654321**
  3  087654567        6  087654567     

                                  I was trying to solve this using windows batch file. Wondering why the following doesn't work :

     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (ns.txt) do ( if /I %%A EQU "9"  CALL:Sub %%A
                              echo %%A >>z.txt )
    goto:eof
    :Sub
    set B=0%1
    echo !B! >>z.txt
    goto:eof
```

Comment: What do you expect `%%A` to be? Both just `9` when you compare it and `978654321` as parameter with `call`?

Comment: The only modification I am seeking is the addition (prefix)of the zero to the numerical strings. I guess that the problem here is the first command within the do loop is not working. I have tested the subroutine independently and it returns the expected values using the` findstr /b "9"` command on the file.My reasoning was that since the for command would filter the strings whatever was passed to the subroutine would be a numerical string.So it was just a matter of prefixing a 0 to the input. Is there a generic way of representing a string that begins with "9" for string comparisions.

Answer (score 0):

it's the part `if /I %%A EQU "9"` that's not working - well it IS working, but not like you seem to think.

Let's assume, `%%A` is `987654321`. Your comparison then is:

```
if /i 987654321 equ "9"
```

obviously not.

I would push the comparison into your subfunction:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (ns.txt) do CALL:Sub %%A
goto:eof

:Sub
set A=%1
REM next line: compare first letter of %A% :
if "%A:~0,1%"=="9" (set B=0%1) else set B=%1
echo %B% >>z.txt
goto:eof
```

(you don't need delayed expansion here)

that's not the best way to do it, but easy to understand.

Comment: see my solution.  Hint : "==" ?

Answer (score 0):

Man o Man ! God knows how many people have committed suicide trying to figure out the syntax that makes the goddamn computer understand what you want.I managed to solve my problem and gain fresh insights.

```
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (ns.txt) do ( set C=%%A
    If /I "!C:~0,1!" equ "9" (echo 0!C! >>j.txt)  else (echo !C! >>j.txt)

      )
   goto:eof
```

The blessed compare-op "equ" was the problem when you use the negative in an expression ie "NOT" you use "==" otherwise you got to use "equ" or your processor goes mad and in turn drives you up the wall